# package installing issue

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies, testdisk

I was trying to install libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev and mesa-common-dev on lubuntu due to an online course that requires opengl to run the code for the exercices and initially it raised an error due to som dependencies, but I ended up holding broken packages, as I didn't know how to solve it I googled it and found someone saying to do this:
  1  sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
  2  sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf 
  3  sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
however I'm still holding broken packages and yet can't purge them because it says they are not installed, I don't know if that's because of the files I removed (and I made a mistake: I did it without doing first a backup of the files on /var/lib/apt/lists nor searhing for another solution first) or I could purge it before, I've tried to recover the files using testdisk, but the option "undelete" doesn't apear. I've also tried using gparted selecting "Attempt data rescue" on "Devices" it found this file system: "#1. ext2/3/4, ReiserFS or XFS (size of my hard disk)" when I click view it displays an error message: "the file system couldn't be mounted (as swap) due to inconsistencies on the file system". The output of the command history (on the relevant lines - that is: the ones since I started trying to install the packages) is the following:
 242  sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev
  243  sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev libgll-mesa-dev libxext-dev libxt-dev libxll-dev
  244  sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev libgll-dev libxext-dev libxt-dev libxll-dev
  245  sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev libgl-dev libxext-dev libxt-dev libxll-dev
  246  sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev libgl-dev libxext-dev libxt-dev libx11-dev
  247  sudo apt-get install -f libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev
  248  sudo apt-get --fix-broken install -f libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev
  249  sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
  250  rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf 
  251  sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf 
  252  sudo apt-get update 
  253  aptitude safe-upgrade 
  254  sudo aptitude safe-upgrade 
  255  sudo aptitude install --force libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev
  256  sudo aptitude install -f libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev
  257  sudo apt-get install -f libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev
  258  sudo apt-get purge -f libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev
  259  reboot
  260  sudo apt-get install -f libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev
  261  sudo apt-get purge -f libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev
  262  sudo apt-get clean 
  263  sudo apt-get update 
  264  sudo apt-get install -f libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev
  265  sudo dpkg --configure -a
  266  sudo apt-get install -f libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev
  267  sudo apt-get autoremove 
  268  sudo apt-get install -f libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev
  269  sudo aptitude -f install libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev
  270  sudo aptitude -f purge libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev
  271  sudo aptitude -f purge libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev libgl-dev libxext-dev libxt-dev libx11-dev
  272  sudo apt-get --fix-missing update 
  273  sudo apt-get install -f libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev
  274  sudo apt-get update 
  275  sudo apt-get autoclean 
  276* sudo apt-get 
  277  sudo dpkg --configure -a
  278  sudo dpkg -l | grep ^..r
  279  sudo -i gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
  280  sudo -i leafpad /var/lib/dpkg/status
  281  sudo cat /var/lib/dpkg/status | grep "Status:"
  282  sudo cat /var/lib/dpkg/status | grep "Status: [^install ok installed]"
  283  sudo cat /var/lib/dpkg/status | grep "Status: [^sgdk]"
  284  sudo cat /var/lib/dpkg/status | grep "Status: [^"install ok installed"]"
  285  sudo cat /var/lib/dpkg/status | grep "Status: ^[install ok installed]"
  286  sudo cat /var/lib/dpkg/status | grep "Status: ^install ok installed"
  287  sudo cat /var/lib/dpkg/status | grep "Status:" | grep -v "install ok installed"
  288  sudo cat /var/lib/dpkg/status | grep "Status:" | grep -v "ok"
  289  sudo cat /var/lib/dpkg/status | grep -n "Status:" | grep -v "ok"
  290  sudo cat /var/lib/dpkg/status | grep -n "Status:" | grep -v "install ok installed"
  291  sudo -i leafpad /var/lib/dpkg/status
  292  sudo aptitude install testdisk
  293  testdisk 
  294  sudo aptitude install gpart
  295  dpkg --get-selections | grep "hold"
  296  dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
  297  synaptic
  298  sudo synaptic
  299  sudo ls -l /var/lib/apt/lists/
  300  testdisk 
  301  history

Comment: Please provide OS/release details, and copy/paste the actual command & error message into your question (also if you get any errors when you `sudo apt update` those errors maybe helpful, plus any errors you get with `sudo apt -f install`)

Comment: "Held broken packages" does not usually mean that the packages themselves are corrupt. It usually means that you have unwisely added non-Ubuntu sources, and that those sources have --in turn-- provided packages that conflict with your release of Ubuntu. The usual solution is to remove those non-Ubuntu soruces, and to uninstall all packages that you installed from those non-Ubuntu sources.

Comment: release: 18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)

Comment: sudo apt update doesn't raise any error just says that 2 packages can be updated/upgraded

Comment: sudo apt -f install libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev:
Os pacotes a seguir têm dependências desencontradas:
 freeglut3-dev : Depende: libgl1-mesa-dev mas não será instalado ou
                          libgl-dev
                 Depende: libxext-dev mas não será instalado
                 Depende: libxt-dev mas não será instalado
 libglu1-mesa-dev : Depende: libgl1-mesa-dev mas não será instalado ou
                             libgl-dev
 mesa-common-dev : Depende: libx11-dev mas não será instalado
E: Impossível corrigir problemas, você manteve (hold) pacotes quebrados.

Comment: unfortunately I cant paste images in the comments so they are a little messed

Comment: I'm Brazilian so my os is in portuguese, but the translation of the error message is: the following packages have unmet dependencies: freeglut3-dev : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dev but it's not going to be installed or libgl-dev Depends: libxext-dev but it's not going to be installed Depends: libxt-dev but it's not going to be installed libglu1-mesa-dev : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dev but it's not going to be installed or libgl-dev mesa-common-dev : Depende: libx11-dev but it's not going to be installed E: Impossible to fix problems, you held broken packages.

Comment: it makes much more sense with the indent but I can't paste screen captures on the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem I just needed to use aptitude but I was confused because the first option it showed to me was to do nothing so when I ran it before it did nothing I just had to don't accept the first option and choose the second instead thanks to you all.